# if one argparse action is true get another value

Tags: python, argparse

I am new to python and trying below code. All I need is if one of the argarse value is true, get another value.

```
#! /home/y/bin/python3
import argparse
__author__ = "Yogesh"


parser =  argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is demo script')
parser.add_argument('-s','--source_host', help='Source Host Name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-d','--dest_host',help='Destination Host Name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-n','--user_count',help="No of users to migrate",required=False)
parser.add_argument('--action', choices=['one-week', 'two-week','user-count','all-users'], default='all-users')

args = parser.parse_args()

print("Source Host:{0}".format(args.source_host))
print("Dest Host:{0}".format(args.dest_host))
if args.action == 'one-week':
    print("Migrate one week active users".format(args.action))
elif args.action == 'two-week':
    print("Migrate two week active users".format(args.action))
elif args.action == 'user-count':
    print("Mingrate user_count".format(args.action))
else:
    print("Migrate all users ".format(args.action))
```

All I am looking is if user-count is true then code should be prompt for --user_count.  Thanks much.

Comment: If you're going to have completely unrelated behaviors for different actions, you might want to [use sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands); that lets you have a single initial argument that determines which set of features apply, with the main parser recognizing common arguments, and each subparser able to implement additional arguments unique to it.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You may want to post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes expected output to get better answers.

Comment: `argparse` looks at the strings provided in the command line - when the script is called.  It's not an interactive input.  You could follow up with an `input`, but that's not the usual way of using command line parsing.  Usually we expect the user to provide all needed information at the start.  If they don't we raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the conditional statement. I guess this is what you wanted to do.

```
if args.action == 'one-week':
    print("Migrate one week active users".format(args.action))
elif args.action == 'two-week':
    print("Migrate two week active users".format(args.action))
elif args.action == 'user-count':
    user_count = input('Enter user count: ')
    print("Mingrate {user_count} users".format(user_count=user_count))
else:
    print("Migrate all users ".format(args.action))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. found a workaround as below. But still would be great to know if there is a option as asked in original question

```
parser =  argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is demo script')
parser.add_argument('-s','--source_host', help='Source Host Name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-d','--dest_host',help='Destination Host Name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-n','--user_count',help="No of users to migrate",required=False)
parser.add_argument('--action', choices=['one-week', 'two-week','user-count','all-users'], default='all-users')


args = parser.parse_args()

print("Source Host:{0}".format(args.source_host))
print("Dest Host:{0}".format(args.dest_host))
if args.action == 'one-week':
    print("Migrate one week active users".format(args.action))
elif args.action == 'two-week':
    print("Migrate two week active users".format(args.action))
elif args.action == 'user-count':
    if args.user_count:
        print("Mingrate user_count".format(args.action))
        print("No of users:-{0}".format(args.user_count))
    else:
        print("Provide no of users you want to migrate with -n option")
else:
    print("Migrate all users ".format(args.action))
```